# what techniques should we use to prevent auto-login by pasting cookies?

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net, jsp

I read http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html

> Log into a website, copy the essential
>   cookie values, then paste them into
>   another browser running on another
>   computer. That's all it takes. It's
>   quite an eye opener.

My question is, does this method also work if we use php/aspnet sessions.

And if it does work, what techniques can we (as web developers) employ to prevent this trick from working. Basically I do not wish the user to be able to login to his account just by pasting cookies, a password is a MUST.

If the above is not possible, does it mean that even for google products like Gmail, I will have some way to login into my account without requiring my password?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sessions are sessions - accomplished by storing an ID token in a cookie. YOu cannot prevent the cookies from being manually copied between browsers.

You can attempt to do things like logging the original User-Agent string when they log in, and compare each time (if they logged in with Firefox, and are suddenly using Opera, hmmMmMmmmmmm). Same for IP addresses... but IP addresses are problematic for mobile users and people behing multi-homed proxy server systems, such as most of AOL and the like. Their IP can potentially change for EVERY request.

There's no foolproof method of preventing cookie sharing that can't be bypassed (change your browser's UA so they ALL claim to be a single type/version), or produce false-positives (IP changes due to proxies).

Comment: Cookies aren't the only possible method of tracking the user's session - they're just the most common because they're the easiest to implement.

Comment: True. But the only other method is hidden form fields and in the URL, which leads to far easier session stealing than cookies alone.

Comment: Does it mean that even for google products like Gmail, I will have some way to login into my account without requiring my password?

Comment: Sure, as you keep visiting the site periodically to keep the session alive. One-time tokens get around this, but they're not as easy to use.

Comment: So i read your answer and implemented a User-Agent string, which will be checked every pagerequest.. but now I have a AJAX-Xmlhttprequest which should pass me data of another page on my domain.. this request fails now because the UserAgent dont are the same.. Any ideas??

Answer (score 2):

Well, as a creator of a software that can capture any cookie over HTTP successfully, if you want security, there are a few tips:

-Use HTTPS when possible to prevent OTHERS to capture that cookie first.

The answer to your question: there is no one concrete way. You can make it harder, which will also make your job (and your server's) harder.

-Expire the cookies after some short time at the server side, so even if the user copy pastes the cookie, it just won't be a valid one.

-Save some metadata with a cookie too, such as remote IP and user agent string or some other headers.

These are the best and most straightforward tips you can use, but just have in mind that an experienced user can overcome most of these problems. Just don't leave anything about the security to client side, finish it at the server side as a golden rule.

Comment: Does it mean that even for google products like Gmail, I will have some way to login into my account without requiring my password?

Comment: Yes. Just for demonstration purposes (do not try this at a network) I was able to login into my friends' any website account (that wasn't using HTTPS. HTTPS can't be captured by regular means). Even if I can capture my friends' cookies to login, they themselves can surely do. So if carrying cookies (which are browser dependent) and putting them into their appropriate location on another PC (which is not always an easy task for all browsers) is easier than typing a password, then yes, it exactly means that :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure if it is a problem with php/asp.net session. One way it can be prevented is by adding IP validation to the cookie, and if it is sent from an IP different than it was created for, throw it to login.

Comment: Does it mean that even for google products like Gmail, I will have some way to login into my account without requiring my password?